# reverse error in django not showing what it cant reverse

Tags: django

I don't think I am reversing '' but still I am getting an error: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Don't know where the source of error is because it is not showing what reverse is not found.
[image]

urls.py

```
    url(r'^search_page/$', views.index, name='search_page'),
url(r'^search_customer/$',views.ajax_customer_search,name='search_customer'),
```

template:base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Django/jQuery AJAX Search</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>

{% block extra_js %}

{% endblock %}
    </head>

<body>
<div id="centered">

{% block main %}{% endblock %}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

template:index.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_js %}

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( "#searchSubmit" ).click( function() {
q = $( "#q" ).val();
$( "#results" ).html( "&nbsp;" ).load( "{% url search_customer %}?q=" + q );
});
});

$( document ).ajaxStart( function() {
$("#spinner").show();
}).ajaxStop( function() {
$( "#spinner" ).hide();
});
</script>

{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div>
<input id="q" type="text"/>
<input id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
<br/>
<span class="hint">Type in a query string to search for users</span>
<div class="margin">
<span id="spinner"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif"/></span>
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
{% if results|length %}

<table>
<tr class="even">
<td colspan="3" class="right">
<strong>Found {{ results|length }} users</strong>
</td>
</tr>

{% for user in results %}
    <tr class="{% cycle "odd" "even" %}“>
<td><strong>{{ forloop.counter }}.</strong></td>
<td>
{{ user.fName }} {{ user.lName}}<br>
<span class="hint">{{ user.id}}</span>
</td>
<td class="right">
done
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
    </table>
{% else %}
    <div class="note">
Your search yielded no results
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: just posting the error won't help you need to share your template and urls.

Comment: It's empty because you're passing an empty value to the url tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your index.py file try

```
$( "#results" ).html( "&nbsp;" ).load( "{% url 'search_customer' %}?q=" + q );
```